# countdown timer in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am javascript impaired - I need to build a countdown script that counts down 45 minutes and appends the remaining time into the title bar or the users browser, as well as when the time is up will operate a function like an alert message.

I wish I had code to start with.

Comment: What have you already tried? In what intervals should the time increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, this should work for you. [(Demo)](http://jsbin.com/uqinic/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var interval;
    var minutes = 1;
    var seconds = 5;
    window.onload = function() {
        countdown('countdown');
    }

    function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";  
                    alert("countdown's over!");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
            document.title = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='countdown'></div>
</body>
</html>
```